# How can I make my bed non-box-spring frame stop squeaking?

Tags: bedroom

I have a foam mattress which rests ontop of a wooden frame (no box springs, just wooden framing).  I have had it for over 6 months and now, even the slightest movement causes the wood to squeak.  Is there a simple way to remedy this?

Answer (score 2):

The frame is squeaking because two pieces of wood are rubbing against eachother.  The first thing I would do is start tightening any screws, nuts and bolts on the bed frame.  If this does not improve it you will need to locate where the squeak is coming from and determine if you can do something to hold the two components together better, such as driving a screw through the affected area.

Comment: If it is not feasible to put a screw through the affected area, you can try lubricating it by rubbing a bar of soap or a wax candle in that spot. Assuming of course it is not visible.

Comment: If you are capable of disassembling it, I've had luck by putting cork board or the like into the joint.